# Selenium Chrome Driver Nightmare (nodejs)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to setup tests with NodeJS, Selenium & Jest.  They work fine on my Mac but both a Windows and Linux install are failing with similar errors:

WITHOUT THE PATH EXPLICITLY SET

> WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
>
> ```
>   at Object.throwDecodedError (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:522:15)
>   at parseHttpResponse (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:548:13)
>   at Executor.execute (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:474:28)
> ```

WITH THE PATH EXPLICITLY SET

> WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited
> abnormally.
> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
> (The process started from chrome location /usr/local/bin/chromedriver is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is
> assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

FWIW on a linux machine running `chromedriver` directly I get this:

> Starting ChromeDriver 98.0.4758.80
> (7f0488e8ba0d8e019187c6325a16c29d9b7f4989-refs/branch-heads/4758@{#972})
> on port 9515 Only local connections are allowed. Please see
> https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for
> suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe. ChromeDriver was started
> successfully.

Setting the path directly has not worked, using a globally installed (`/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`) binary and a local one `node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver`).  None of the following options has made any difference:

```
    .addArguments([
        "--ignore-certificate-errors",
        "--disable-extensions",
        "--disable-popup-blocking",
        "--enable-automation",
        "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--headless",
        "--log-path=/home/jsp/projects/proj/selenium/chrome.log",
        "--append-log",
        "--verbose",
        "--enable-chrome-logs",
        "--port=9222"
    ])
```

Enabling logging generated an empty `chrome.log` file.  I tried simplifying and this is what I ended up with that again works on my Mac but not on the Linux test box.

```
const { Builder } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");

let chromeTest = async () => {

    let options = new chrome.Options()
        .setChromeBinaryPath('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
        .addArguments(["headless", "ignore-certificate-errors", "disable-dev-shm-usage", "no-sandbox"]);

    let driver = await new Builder()
        .forBrowser("chrome")
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .build();

    await driver.quit();
};

chromeTest();
```

Selenium: 4.1.1
ChromeDriver: 98.0.4758.80
Ubuntu 20.04.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to provide the path AND the web driver's .exe file name (i.e. _/usr/local/bin/chromedriver.exe_)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but this is Linux so it's an ELF 64-bit binary that does not have an extension.  Also I can directly run it via `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` which also happens to be in my path so `chromedriver` also runs it.